# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on an internal class when running tests from Maven on Java 11

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, classnotfoundexception

I've got a project that looks like this:

```
Parent project
   | Core
   | Subproject 1
       | dependent on Core
   | Subproject 2
       | dependent on Core
   | Subproject 3
       | dependent on Core and Subproject 1
etc...
```

originally built on Java 8 that I would like to upgrade to Java 11.

Everything works OK including tests in each sub project, apart from three specific integration tests in one of the sub projects, that pass when run using Eclipse (via JUnit) but not when run via Maven (mvn integration-test).

They all throw:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/../../../SomeDAO (from Core)
    at <package-name>@<version>/<one of the submodules>.initialize(<class>.java:47)
    at <package-name>@<version>/<one of the submodules>.setup(<class>.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/../../../SomeDAO (from Core)
    at <package-name>@<version>/<one of the submodules>.initialize(<class>.java:47)
    at <package-name>@<version>/<one of the submodules>.setup(<class>.java:41)
```

the other tests fail for the same reason, but there is nothing special about that DAO class or those tests.

Also, my test lives in Subproject 1/src/test, which imports a utility class from Core which *then* imports the actual DAO (from Core as well).
This obviously means that Subproject 1 has Core in its classpath and can access it just fine - classes are public.

The project is running Java 11, JUnit 5 and Mockito 3.6.
I'm using Maven 3.6 and no Java 11 modules (in my code base).
Has anyone seen any similar behaviour after upgrading to Java 11?

**EDIT:**

- I did run Maven -> Update project in Eclipse
- I've upgraded Mockito to the latest minor version after seeing this issue
- I've tried a more recent minor Java 11 version
- I've tried moving the DAO to another package
- I've tried to import the DAO directly into the test class (in the event he class wasn't being imported correctly in the classpath)
- the DAO imports java.sql and java.util classes (although java.util classes are surely imported by other tests)

**EDIT:** Here's my sub-project pom file: https://pastebin.com/U7zGU5iN

Comment: Stop using eclipse. It's considered unprofessional for the very reason you've outlined here. There is a community edition of IntelliJ that's free and much, much, much better.

Comment: I also tried to use IntelliJ, Eclipse is a company decision - IntelliJ also does the same: when running the tests they all work, but they fail if you run `maven integration-test`

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Does not help to solve the problem. Personal opinion. XCore: please show the pom of your module where integration test are located?

Comment: @khmarbaise sure thing, please see my new edit